# Laravel adds <!----> to json response

Tags: json, php-7, php-7.4, laravel-7

I'm trying to fetch json data from my Laravel 7 project but when I do

`return response()->json(["test" => "test"]);`

the result I get is always: `<!---->{"test":"test"}`

I have no idea where `<!---->` gets added.

I have tried
 `return ["test" => "test"]` and `return json_encode(["test" => "test"])`
and I still get the same result of `<!---->{"test":"test"}`

I'm using Laravel 7 with php 7.4

**Note** I just upgraded from Laravel 5.6 to 7

any help would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: `return response()->json(["test" => "test"]);` change to `return response()->json_decode(["test" => "test"]);`or `return response()->json(["test" => "test"], 200, [], JSON_UNESCAPED_UNICODE);`

Comment: Thanks for the suggestions: ```return response()->json_decode(["test" => "test"]);``` failed with exception function does not exist ```return response()->json(["test" => "test"], 200, [], JSON_UNESCAPED_UNICODE);``` still no change in result getting ```<!---->{"test":"test"}```

Answer (score 1):

So I found the issue
while upgrading from laravel 5.6 to laravel 7 the string `<!---->` got added to my `public/index.php`
The system worked fine until you tried to do any API calls and then you got that string

How I found it:  I installed a fresh laravel 7 install and just did a folder comparison with meld.
I should have just searched for that string in my code base

thanks